# How Can I Know When NSTextView Loses Focus?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, focus, nstextview

I want to clear the selection of `NSTextView` after it loses focus. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Kai.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up a delegate object (or use your app delegate) that conforms to `NSTextDelegate` protocol. Then all you need to do is to implement `textDidEndEditing:` to clear the selection. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextDelegate/textDidEndEditing%3a):

> **textDidEndEditing:**
>
> Informs the delegate that the text object has finished
>   editing (that it has resigned first responder status).
>
> `- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

Something like:

```
#ifndef NSZeroRange
#define NSZeroRange NSMakeRange(0,0)
#endif

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [myTextView setSelectedRange:NSZeroRange];
}
```